# Fill empty rows until find next value

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's possible to have and update (T-SQL) to fill the empty rows with the previous value, until find a row with value

| id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | May 24, 2022 |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |
| 4 | NULL |
| 5 | NULL |
| 6 | NULL |
| 7 | NULL |
| 8 | May 23, 2022 |
| 9 | NULL |
| 10 | NULL |

That's the column, I would like to write the "May 24, 2022", until the value "May 23,2022" and then "May 23,2022" until the next not NULL column

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: provide other columns in order to provide better result

Comment: You will need to provide more info such that the primary key of the table; there is nothing that indicates which null rows are "before" or "after" any other row.

Comment: @RF1991 the other columns its text and they are all ok. What kind of column is needed for that to work?

Comment: @Stu it's updated

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use a correlated subquery in an `update`:

```
update t 
  set date = (select min(date) from t t2 where t2.id < t.id)
where date is null
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4a775a1ea6f2b15e66074de85c41392a)

Comment: It is not guaranteed that the date is always greater in id 1

Answer (score 0):

We would like to use last_value but ignore nulls doesn't work in SQL Server.
We can use a CTE and inline sub-query.

> ```
> create table t(id int, date_ varchar(10));
> insert into t values (1,'2022-05-24'),(8,'2022-05-23');
> insert into t (id) values(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(9),(10);
> ```

10 rows affected

> 

> ```
> with cte as(
> select 
>   id, 
>   date_,
>   (select max(id) from t t2 where t2.id <= t.id and date_ is not null ) idd
> from t)
> select
>   id,
>   (select date_ from cte c where c.id = d.idd) "date"
> from cte d
> order by id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | date      
> -: | :---------
>  1 | 2022-05-24
>  2 | 2022-05-24
>  3 | 2022-05-24
>  4 | 2022-05-24
>  5 | 2022-05-24
>  6 | 2022-05-24
>  7 | 2022-05-24
>  8 | 2022-05-23
>  9 | 2022-05-23
> 10 | 2022-05-23
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=b90b5c5f02b1545f2b80b00fd3fd875d)*